# Unable to open port in google compute engine

Tags: port, google-compute-engine

I'm trying to open the port 29765 port on a VM instance in Google Compute Engine.I created a firewall rule as per below instructions and restarted the VM after creation. But it doesn't work. Can someone help me by providing some advice and if I'm supposed to do anything else ?

It's a Windows platform.

https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/using-firewalls

- Go to cloud.google.com
- Go to my Console
- Choose your Project
- Choose Networking > VPC network
- Choose "Firewalls rules"
- Choose "Create Firewall Rule"
- Target: All instances of network Source : 0.0.0.0/0
  To allow incoming TCP connections to port 29765, in "Protocols and Ports" entered tcp:29765
- Click Create

Comment: How are you checking and confirming that its not working? What do you have listening on port 29765 ?

Comment: I'm doing telnet to that port

Comment: "It doesn't work" is not descriptive. Provide exactly what is happening -- logs, error messages, your testing method, etc -- so that we can help you.